# objective define constants according to device type

Tags: objective-c, iphone, constants, extern

Hi I am building one Iphone application in which I am defining few constants. I know many people ask same question but I am not able to figure it out. So my problem is like this. I am defining my constant values in one file say `constants.m` and `constants.h`. SO my `constant.h` looks like :

```
@interface Constants : NSObject
    //  UI CONSTANTS
    extern int FONT_SIZE_14;
 @end
```

And my `constants.m` looks like :

```
@implementation Constants

    //  UI CONSTANTS.

    #if (IS_IPAD)
        int FONT_SIZE_14 = 18;
    #else
        int FONT_SIZE_14 = 14;
    #endif
@end
```

So it works fine without any error but it always takes only value 14. If it is running on ipad it is not taking 18 value. Am doing anything wrong. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: What did you defined as 'IS_IPAD'?

Comment: I tried it with `#define IS_IPAD    (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` but then it gives me error at if condition for preprocessor condition.

Answer (score 0):

if you support both ipad and iphone, you won't know the device until runtime.

You can use something like this :

```
int myFontSize() {
  switch (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()) {
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone :
      return FONT_SIZE_14;
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad :
      return FONT_SIZE_18;
    default :
  }
}
```

or you can use a define constant :

```
#define MY_CONSTANT_Font ( (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? FONT_SIZE_14 : FONT_SIZE_18
```

Comment: No reason. I generally define my utility functions like this.

Comment: @samir thank you for your help. Can you please tell me difference between two methods. WHen I tried with preprocessor methods that time it gives me single value which is not correct one. Why it is ? Any reason ?

Comment: I did with your second method and it works fine. But I am not able get the difference between two methods. Is there any difference.